# UIViewController inheritance with UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

i created a class BaseViewController with inheritance of UIViewController. My problem is when i'll create a new view controller that inherit BaseViewController, the delegate that i used not works.

See my BaseViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

my SecondViewController

```
@interface SecondViewController : BaseViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar;
    UIPickerView *textPickerView;
}
```

If i change BaseViewController, for UIViewController it works. But if i use BaseViewController, my PickerView not works.
What happen ?

Comment: What specifically about your picker view does not work? does it display? Can you interact with it? does it not fire selection events? Also helpful would be to post your code where you create the UIPickerView, and where you handle the delegate methods.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Provide more specifics as mentioned by Ryan's comment.

Comment: Not works... when I click nothing happens, and if i change BaseViewController to UIViewController, it works! My BaseViewController http://pastebin.com/FLuNnEd7 and my SecondViewController http://pastebin.com/LRcCBK8z

Comment: I wanted to know why when I changed for UIViewController everything works

Comment: @ryancumley see my source

Comment: @rmaddy see my source